# chrome.filesystem save file without prompt location

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

can i save file in custom location (`/home/Users/user1/`) with name `file1.txt`.

I have this code:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
    chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(entry, function(entry) {
        entry.getFile('file1.txt', {create:true}, function(entry) {
            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.write(new Blob(['Lorem'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

With this code, i get prompt so i need to choose directory, but i want without that, i wanna declare directory location in settings.

Any solution for this?

**EDIT**

According to accepted answer from @Xan :

```
// set location
$('#location_field').on('click', function(){
    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'print_location': chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(entry)});
    });
});

// get location 
var print_location = null;
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    print_location: null
}, function(items){
    chrome.fileSystem.restoreEntry(items.print_location, function(entry){
        print_location = entry;
    });
});

// save file
chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(print_location, function(entry) {
    entry.getFile('file1.txt', {create:true}, function(entry) {
        entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.write(new Blob(['Lorem'], {type: 'text/plain'}));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably shouldn't have all your arguments named `entry`.

Comment: I agree, this was example i found, so i used it to check if it works..

Comment: Quick request: could you move your solution out into a separate answer? It would be helpful to keep to Q&A format (and you'll get extra rep this way!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You cannot pre-select a path to be readable/writable - it always has to go through a user confirmation to gain the Entry object. Consider it a security feature.

However, if you declare the "retainEntries" sub-permission, you can ask only once and then reuse the entry.

See documentation for [`retainEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-retainEntry) and [`restoreEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-restoreEntry).

Also, you may try to provide a `suggestedName` for `chooseEntry` if you know where you want it to ideally be. I'm not sure if it will work if you provide an absolute path though.