# Javascript: Path to download

Tags: javascript

Here's the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width = 256;
var h = canvas.height = 256;

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'file:///path/to/file';
img.onload = function () {
    var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
    ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
};

function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    link.download = filename;
}

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', 'thumb.png');
}, false);
```

I am creating Chrome Extension, I have permission to use 'file:///...'. I am able to see the file, also able to download the file. The file gets downloaded to Downloads folder. I need to download it to 'file:///here'. How can I do it?

Tried many ways, still can't figure out.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_filesystem more advanced overview. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894660/chrome-filesystem-save-file-without-prompt-location helps too.

Comment: link.download is using the browsers download function and as you may know, if you download files from a webpage, the page cannot determine the download path. You have to use the file system api of chrome to achieve what you want.